# closing a window breaks event loop assumption

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I've have encountered a small annoyance that blows up to be a huge problem.

**Problem 1:** In Internet Explorer when you close a window (that you opened via `window.open`) the `ownerDocument` will disappear along with it.

The implication of this is that any call to the DOM, such as `appendChild` or `createElement`, will fail with a `SCRIPT70: Permission Denied` or `SCRIPT1717: The interface is unknown`.

I've looked at the behaviour of other browsers such as Chrome. In Chrome `ownerDocument` still references the `#document` but `ownerDocument.defaultView` will eventually be `undefined`. This makes sense to me. Calls to `appendChild` and `createElement` will pass. I think everything is fine so long as you don't try to reference the `defaultView` directly.

**Problem 2:** In Internet Explorer when you click on the close button of the spawned window it doesn't seem to respect the Event loop. I attached an `unload` event to the spawned window and it fires *immediately* instead of queuing it at the end of the Event loop. This does *not* make sense to me. It becomes quite impossible to deal with this rather trivial problem.

If we just had *problem 1* there would be a -still painful but- straightforward solution: check if the `ownerDocument` exists and skip if it doesn't. As it is `ownerDocument` disappears in the middle of synchronous JavaScript code.

**Expected behaviour:** a DOM node should not disappear if you've referenced it - garbage collection sanity.

**Expected behaviour 2:** a DOM node should not disappear in synchronous code. (unless you delete it of course).

**Known workaround:** move all the code that interacts with the DOM into the window, so that when the window is closed so is the JavaScript runtime environment. This is not a trivial solution and may require significant changes in your architecture.

**Crappy solution:** wrap any function that does interaction with the DOM in a function that will consume errors if it detects the window of the element has been closed. This is quite invasive and has a significant impact on performance, and IE is already so slow.

Is there a better solution?

What I want, at the very least, is a way to *ignore* any `Error`s that are thrown because the user closed a window. *problem 1* and *problem 2* break basic assumptions you make about JavaScript code: garbage collection and event loop.

---

**Demo script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function go() {
    var popup = window.open('', 'open', 'width=500,height=300,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
    popup.document.open();
    popup.document.write('<html><head></head><body></body></html>');
    popup.document.close();
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) {
        var node = popup.document.createTextNode(i + " ");
        popup.document.body.appendChild(node);
    }
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="go();" value="Open popup" />
```

(save as .html file)

Instructions:

- Open in Internet Explorer 9
- Click "Open popup"
- Close the window while it's rendering
- Observe "Permission Denied"

Here it is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C9p2R/1/

Comment: Does this happen in all IE versions?

Comment: It occurs in IE9. I haven't dare test older versions. I don't know about IE10.

Comment: Do I understand right that Chrome lets you modifiy the DOM of closed windows as long as you hold references to it? And you want that behaviour in IE?

Comment: "*ownerDocument disappears in the middle of synchronous JavaScript code*" - how do you have so long-running sync code that you can close a window during its execution?

Comment: @Bergi Yes you get to keep references to the `DOM#document` in Chrome (indefinitely for as I can tell). "Long running" is relative, but IE9 is very slow. A script that runs in under 2 seconds in Chrome takes about 20 in IE9. I can extend the execution time easily by just repeating the steps. When I look at the behaviour in Chrome I see that it does respect the expected behaviour of the Event loop. The Window might visually disappear but JavaScript wont get the `unload` event till it's completed earlier events (as it should).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless anyone has a better solution, I'll go with the *crappy solution*. Here is my code:

```
function apply_window_close_fix(dom_element, wrapped_element) {
    var ignore_errors = false;
    dom_element.ownerDocument.defaultView.addEventListener("unload", function () {
        ignore_errors = true;
    });
    return map(wrapped_element, function (key, func) {
        return function () {
            try {
                return func.apply(this, arguments);
            } catch (e) {
                if (ignore_errors === false) {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        };
    });
}
```

`wrapped_element` is the API that I return for modifying the DOM. I've wrapped all functions in a try-catch that will ignore errors if it sees the window has been closed. I call this function only for browsers that behave like Internet Explorer does.

There seems to be only a very minor performance hit. Of course this depends on how intensively you call this API.

One minor downside is that currently rethrowing *some* Errors is broken in some browsers. Rethrowing a DOMException resets the stack in Internet Explorer and Chrome (and possibly others). I've also found no way to fetch a filename and linenumber from a DOMException in Internet Explorer. Once again, a gross oversight that just ends up wasting time for everybody.

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your "Crappy Solution".  Instead of wrapping the functions that interact with DOM, you can redefine them when the `unload` event is fired in such a way that they don't interact with the DOM, e.g. `myOldFunction = function (){};`.

Comment: This doesn't work. When the `unload` event occurs the other event loop is in the middle of processing some other function (like making DOM Nodes and setting properties). You can not retroactively wrap a function that's already been called.

Comment: Then you could make sure that the functions pushed into the event loop call other functions that do the DOM manipulation for you without doing any DOM manipulation themselves.  Then you could use the `unload` event to redefine the functions that do the DOM manipulation before they get called from the functions that are already in the event loop.

Comment: I understand your suggestion and I've tried it but I've had no success. I tried keeping track of all the DOM elements I make, and then replacing their functions by empty functions and properties by dummy properties. It has no effect what so ever. Have you tried this before? Do you have a solution that works? In theory I agree that it should work but in theory I shouldn't be having this problem either.

Comment: Can you post an example that throws the `Permission Denied` error you mentioned?  I should be able to modify that with respect to what I have in mind.

Comment: I added a sample script to my question.

Comment: After looking at your sample, it seems like your solution is best.

Answer (score 0):

After trying couple things (postMessage, Worker,... ) always having problems with IE9, I found nice solution. I made Parallel.For loop using setInterval function. Catch is here:

> The setInterval() method will continue calling the function until
>   clearInterval() is called, or the **window is closed**.

Logic for creating nodes is in the child window, but it's triggered from parent window. Loop is executed in chunks and, because setInterval is used, closing of child window at any point doesn't produce errors. More, browser do not hang (neither parent or child while this is running). And it looks like this:

[image]

We have 3 components: parent-ie.html, child-ie.html and small parallel.js file. One quirk was, for all browser to work setInterval(function, -1) was used. Positive values were braking IE, 2nd omitted parameter confuses Opera so it makes only 1st chunk of function. Anyhow, code is here:

**parent-id.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Parent</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        'use strict';
        (function(){
            var popup;
            var pathname = 'child-ie.html';

            window.openPopup = function _open() {
                popup = window.open(pathname, 'open', 'width=500,height=300,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes');
            }

            window.createElements = function _createElements() {
                if (popup == null || popup.closed == true) {
                    alert("Open new popup window first.");
                    return;
                }
                var numberOfElements = parseInt(document.getElementById('numberOfElements').value);
                popup.writeElements(numberOfElements);
            }
        })();
    </script>
    <button onclick="openPopup()">Open popup</button><br />
    <button onclick="createElements()">Create elements</button>
    <input id="numberOfElements" type="number" value="10000" />
</body>
</html>
```

**child-ie.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Child window</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="/Scripts/Parallel.js"></script>
<script>
    (function(){
        function _iterator(index) {
            var node = document.createTextNode(index + " ");
            document.body.appendChild(node);
        }

        window.writeElements = function (numberOfElements) {
            document.body.innerHTML = '';
            Parallel.For(0, numberOfElements, 100, _iterator);
        }
    })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**/Scripts/Parallel.js**

```
'use strict';
var Parallel;
(function (Parallel) {
    var Iterator = (function () {
        function Iterator(from, to, step, expression) {
            this._from = from;
            this._to = to;
            this._step = step;
            this._expression = expression;
        }
        Object.defineProperty(Iterator.prototype, "intervalHandle", {
            set: function (value) {
                this._intervalHandle = value;
            },
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
        Iterator.prototype.next = function () {
            var max = this._to > this._step + this._from ? this._step + this._from : this._to;
            for(var i = this._from; i < max; i += 1) {
                this._expression(i);
            }
            if(max === this._to) {
                clearInterval(this._intervalHandle);
            } else {
                this._from = max;
            }
        };
        return Iterator;
    })();    
    function For(from, to, step, expression) {
        var _iterator = new Iterator(from, to, step, expression);
        _iterator.intervalHandle = setInterval(function () {
            _iterator.next();
        }, -1);
    }
    Parallel.For = For;
})(Parallel || (Parallel = {}));
```

Javascript was generated from typescript file (maybe bit more clear then javascript):

```
'use strict';
module Parallel {
    class Iterator {
        private _from: number;
        private _to: number;
        private _step: number;
        private _expression: (index: number) => {};
        private _intervalHandle: number;

        public set intervalHandle(value: number) {
            this._intervalHandle = value;
        }

        constructor(from: number, to: number, step: number, expression: (index: number) => {}) {
            this._from = from;
            this._to = to;
            this._step = step;
            this._expression = expression;
        }

        next() {
            var max: number = this._to > this._step + this._from ? this._step + this._from : this._to;
            for (var i = this._from; i < max; i += 1) {
                this._expression(i);
            }
            if (max === this._to) {
                clearInterval(this._intervalHandle);
            }
            else {
                this._from = max;
            }
        }
    }
    export function For(from: number, to: number, step: number, expression: (index: number) => {}) {
        var _iterator = new Iterator(from, to, step, expression);
        _iterator.intervalHandle = setInterval(function () {
            _iterator.next();
        }, -1);
    }
}
```

That's all.

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble here but if I had a `child-ie.html` I wouldn't have this problem since I could put all the processing into the child window, which will clean itself up neatly when you close it. Is that it or is there more to this solution? `setInterval` certainly comes with it's own share of performance considerations.

Comment: You made the assumption that I have an iterator-like process, ie. something that is easy to write as an iterative process. The demo does, but that is an over simplification to demonstrate IE9's inexcusable behaviour. I appreciate the effort but I feel like you got a little carried away here.

Comment: Yes, there is more to it. If you just put your loop in child window, it will block parent until operation is done, even when it's closed. Reason, as you mentioned, is that they let operation continue on closed window. IE will throw exception. So simply moving your code to child does not do anything usefull. setInterval let's "event loop" to breath.

Comment: Regarding for-loop, it's just example that ended up being reusable. Could be while-loop, or anything else. You can apply this to any function. It's hard to believe that you have something that cannot be refactored a bit, moved to proper window sliced in chunks. So, pattern is move-code-to-owner-window+setInterval used together. combination.

Comment: There is a very good reason why my code is synchronous, and not asynchronous or even iterator-like. I can not divulge why without disclosing sensitive information. What I can say is that this is an edge case that pops up in my applications, it's very rare and it's very trivial. I find it hard to believe that you find this hard to believe ..

Comment: OK, but I cannot figure all those limitations from reading the question. I posted simplified answer, more generalized, you should be able to extract what you need from it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, let me try to simplify. To gain responsiveness of windows and avoid breaking of application when child is closed, several things have to be combined.

1. Parent should not modify child DOM directly. Functions should be in
   child itself. *However, this alone would not solve anything, if
   functions are triggered from parent and executed synchronously.
   Hanged windows and exceptions are still there.*
2. Main function that parent calls on child has to use `setTimeout` or
   `setInterval`, to schedule DOM-modifying functions, delegate
   execution to the child and return immediately. *This step makes auto-cleanup possible!*
3. Long lasting DOM operations in child should be split to further faster chunks
   using `setTimeout` or `setInterval`, so that events-loop is not locked
   for a long time. *This gives responsiveness to both windows*.

Simplest example of child javascript. Function called from parent is `LongLastingOperation` and it has been split in 4 chunks:

```
<script>
    function wasteTime(message) {
        // TODO: waste time
    }
    function FirstPartOfLongOperation(){
        wasteTime('long... part 1');
        setTimeout(SecondPartOfLongOperation, 0);
    }
    function SecondPartOfLongOperation() {
        wasteTime('long... part 2');
        setTimeout(ThirdPartOfLongOperation, 0);
    }
    function ThirdPartOfLongOperation() {
        wasteTime('long... part 3');
        setTimeout(FourthPartOfLongOperation, 0);
    }
    function FourthPartOfLongOperation() {
        wasteTime('long... part 4');
        alert('Done!');
    }

    // Main entry, called from parent.
    // Ex: popup.LongLastingOperation({ data: ....})
    function LongLastingOperation(parametersPassedFromParentWindow) {
        // decompose long operation
        setTimeout(FirstPartOfLongOperation, 0);
    }
</script>
```